# Increment width from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internationalization

I want to increment the width from right to left.

```
<div dir="rtl" id="progress">
    <dt id='dt'></dt>
    <dd id='dd'></dd>
</div>
```

The main goal is to make this [progress bar](http://blog.ynh.io/2013/05/24/rebuild-youtubes-progress-bar.html#) move from right to left when I use Arabic language in my website (default direction of Arabic language is from right to left).

I tried the attribute `dir` as I wrote, but it didn't fix the problem. I have an idea, but it will change the HTML. That's not the correct thing to do, because my website supports English & Arabic; and I don't want to change the HTML, I just want to change the style or JavaScript code.

Comment: I believe a progress bar should move from left to right whether or not the current language is on rtl mode.

Comment: FYI, the parent of a `<dt>` and `<dd>` should be a `<dl>` instead of a `<div>`.

Comment: @HashemQolami you believe in things that my boss doesn't.

Comment: @GLES you shouldn't change OP's code. Please just do formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't set the initial width to the progress-bar's width for say, and 'shrink' it 
It's just matter of colors..

Answer (score 0):

You can mirror the progress div, by giving it an x scale of -1.

Comment: did it realy disapear or did it just move out of the screen. If its the second you can just add a margin-left equal to the width of the progress

Comment: i scaled the y to 0, this time i scaled it to 1 :D, it has appeared but not mirrored: #progress {
    transform: scale(-1,-1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1,-1);

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Set the `left` property of your progress bar to 100%
- Add the `left` property to your transition (so it will animate smoothly)
- In your javascript, change the `left` position to 0% while increasing the `width` of your progress bar.